# Why is this grammar left recursive?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, context-free-grammar

This grammar is apparently left recursive:

```
S -> 0 A
A -> S 1 | 1
```

And left recursion can be removed by changing the grammar to:

```
S -> 0 A
A -> 0 A 1 | 1
```

But I don't understand why the first grammar is left recursive.  Why is this?

Comment: It's not. Who says it is?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_recursion): 'In terms of context-free grammar, a nonterminal is left-recursive if the leftmost symbol in one of its productions is itself (in the case of direct left recursion) or can be made itself by some sequence of substitutions (in the case of indirect left recursion).' This is not such a grammar. (I don't normally cite Wikipedia but this is the generally accepted definition.)

Comment: If one interprets "0" as epsilon (empty string), it is left recursive, and OP's fix actually fixes the left recursion.  Nobody I know puts epsilon in the middle of a nonempty production, so that's weird but I could understand it.  Is his example the result of a transcription error?  Only OP can tell us...

Comment: @IraBaxter 0, 1 are terminals.  A and S are nonterminals.  Epsilon is not used in this grammar.  EDIT: I think my textbook has a mistake, I agree that the grammar is not left recursive.